# first, second, third maximum name by row of data table

Tags: r, max

I want the first, second, third maximum names by row of data table.
For example:

```
DF <- matrix(sample(1:9,9),ncol=10,nrow=10)
DF <- as.data.frame.matrix(DF)
```

It will return for the first row for example three column `max1`,`max2`,`max3` containing one of v1-v10.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop over the rows, `sort` the elements, and get the first 3 elements

```
t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) head(sort(x, decreasing=TRUE),3)))
```

If we are interested in `unique` values

```
t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) head(unique(sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)),3))
```

Or as @Roland mentioned, if we need the column names

```
t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) head(names(DF)[order(x, decreasing=TRUE)],3)))
```

Comment: I think they might rather want `t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) names(DF)[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]]))`, but am not sure.